# No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ItemsSource', or mismatching type between value and property?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to implement the Project in Xamarin and I am getting following error and not able to resolve it:

**No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ItemsSource', or mismatching type between value and property?**

Xaml code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.Exercises.AirbnbSearchList">
    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar></SearchBar>
        <ListView  x:Name="listView"
              ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
              ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              Refreshing="Handle_Refresh" 
              IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding RecentSearch}" >
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Location}" Detail="{Binding NewProperty}">
                        <TextCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="Delete_Clicked" IsDestructive="True" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></MenuItem>
                        </TextCell.ContextActions>
                    </TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

.CS code is as follow:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Exercises
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AirbnbSearchList : ContentPage
    {
        public SearchService ss = new SearchService();

        public AirbnbSearchList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<Search> list = ss.GetSearches();

            var searchGrp = new SearchGroup("Recent Searches");

            foreach (var listItem in list)
            {
                searchGrp.Add(listItem);
            }

            var searchElement = new ObservableCollection<SearchGroup>();
            searchElement.Add(searchGrp);

            listView.ItemsSource = searchElement;

        }

        void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = ss.GetSearches(e.NewTextValue);
        }

        void Handle_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = ss.GetSearches();
            listView.EndRefresh();
        }

        void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var search = e.Item as Search;
            DisplayAlert("Location", search.Location, "OK");
        }

        void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var search = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Contact;
            //_contacts.Remove(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Search.class file:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Exercises.Models
{
    public class Search
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Location;
        public string CheckIn;
        public string CheckOut;


        public string NewProperty
        {

            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} - {1} / {2}", CheckIn, CheckOut, Location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is SearchGroup:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Exercises.Models
{
     class SearchGroup : List<Search>
    {
        public string RecentSearch;

       public SearchGroup(string recentSearch)
        {
            this.RecentSearch = recentSearch;
        }

    }
}
```

How to resolve this? I've tried searching on Google, but since documentation is so less and this is a specific Error, any solution or tip would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `DataTemplate` meant for items as the items source in XAML, but it should rather be used as the item template. Change `ListView.ItemsSource` and its ending tag to `ListView.ItemTemplate` in your XAML file.